# How to get a Servlet Request attribute in Struts 2.2.1?

Tags: servlets, struts2

I'm reading some tutorial where before invocating any action there is a filter that sets an attribute in the ServletRequest as Connection.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
     Connection connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
     request.setAttribute("connection", connection);
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
     connection.close();
}
```

However I still didn't find a way to get the attribute in my Action. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

Another option is that your action class implements [`ServletRequestAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.html). In the implementation of the method you simply assign the request to an instance field.